# Obtaining a y value that is an integer value from our curve with a given x value

Tags: c++, cryptography, curve

I am working with Elliptic Curve Cryptography and am attempting to obtain a value from my ECC equation. I am utilizing a function that passes in x and I am attempting to loop the code until I get a value for y that is in the form of an integer. As a heads up, please note that I am also using an independent library called InfInt (which handles big Integer values).

Essentially my goal is to find an x that when plugged into the equation y^2 = x^3 + x + 24, will give me a y that is not a decimal number. I am having many issues getting proper results. Is there a solution to the way I am approaching this problem?

CODE WITHIN MAIN______________________________________________________________
//create the seed we need for "true" random x's
    srand(time(NULL));

```
//TEST PROMPT for getting a random point
int x = rand();
cout << ("Given x: ") << (x) << endl <<endl;
InfInt y;
int i = 0;

//TEST to get an exact point, not a decimal value
//while (i == 0) {
    y = getPoint(x);
    if (y == NULL) {
        cout << ("Bad X") << endl;
        x = rand();
        cout << ("Next Attempt at x :") << (x) << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << ("Success!") << endl;
        cout << ("Our point is: (") << (x) << (",") << (y) << (")") << endl;
        i++;
    }
//}
```

GET POINT CODE______________________________________________________________
InfInt getPoint(int x) {

```
double xx = pow(x, 3) + x + 24;

xx = sqrt(xx);
cout << (xx) << endl;
if (xx == int(xx)) {
    y = int(xx);

} else {
    cout << ("Failed!");
        y = NULL;
}

return InfInt(y);
```

}

Comment: I'm a little confused by this part: "...get the proper y value from a given x that is of the integer form without cutting off excess floating point numbers?" Can you try restating what it is you want `x` and `y` to be? My impression was that an integer ought to cut off the decimals.

Comment: I apologize, that is confusing. What I am stating is that I am attempting to cycle through values of x until I get a y that is not a decimal number. Essentially my goal is to find an x that when plugged into the equation y^2 = x^3 + x + 24, will give me a y that is not a decimal number. Is that clearer?

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. I suggest editing your question to help others understand as well [: Anyways, notice how `long long y = xx` is being assigned a value at the very end of your `getPoint()` function. This means that regardless if your function went through the `if` or the `else` block, it y will always be assigned to `xx`. Does changing that help?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. I did pull that portion out though. That was from a previous trial of an attempt to make the code operate properly.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting task you have!

Decided to implement my own solution from scratch in pure C++.

I broke your task into two major parts:

1. When there is no modulus, i.e. you don't take equation `% p` for some prime.
2. When we have a prime modulus meaning that your equation `y^2 = x^3 + x + 24 (mod p)` is taken `% p`, where `p` is prime.

Second part was chosen by me to be implemented because you deal with elliptic curve equation, which is usually take modulus some prime `p`.

First part (without modulus) can be easily solved using two generic algorithms - [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) and [Exponential Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search).

I'm incrementing `x` in a loop while searching for square root of `y^2` using Exponential Search together with Binary Search. It is very easy to see that if we increase `x` then `y` solution is also increased smoothly, hence it is easy to use Exponential Search, because each next "y" is a bit bigger than previous one.

It is well known that both Exponential Search and Binary Search are very fast, they have complexity `O(Log2(segment_size))` meaning that even for 128-bit integers we spend not more than 128 elementary steps inside this algorithm.

Without modulus (x, y) points are very sparse, it happens very rarely that for given X we can find corresponding Y. It needs a lot of computational power to find at least several of solutions. But I found successfully quite small solution `x = 12, y = 42` of your specific equation. More solutions will probably need many hours of 8-16 core machine.

One thing that I used to make program faster is that I used an interesting and simple technique of filtering squares. I took a number `f = 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13`, this number is used as a filter. It is known that if number is a square then it is also a square modulus any composite or prime number, meaning that if N is square then `N % f` is also possibly square. Hence I make precomputed table of size `f` that marks all possibly squares with `true`, and definite non-squares with `false`. This function is called `FilterSquare()` in my code.

I made first part multi-core, meaning that advance CPU with many cores will solve task proportionally faster. If you have N cores (actually N hardware threads) then task will be solved N times faster than with 1 core, using my C++ program.

Second part, with prime modulus P, can be quite easily solved because modulus some prime there is a solution almost always, precisely in 50% of cases.

To remind we do all operations `% p`, both parts of equation are taken `% p`.

This modulus task can be broken into two cases, first case when `p % 4 == 3`, in this case it is well known that if square root of `n` exists then it is equal to `root = n^((p + 1) / 4) (mod p)`, very easy and fast formula to find square root.

Secondly, if `p % 4 == 1` then it is more difficult to find square root, for this case is invented [Tonelli-Shanks Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm), which I fully implemented in my code. Although this algorithms looks quite large, still its computational speed is fast, around `O(Log2(p))`, meaning at most 128 steps for 128-bit prime `p`.

Also it is very easy to filter out X that have no square root solution just by [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion), this criterion says that if we need to find a square root of `n (mod p)` then if `n^((p-1)/2) (mod p)` is 1 then `n` has a square root, and if it is -1 then it has NO square root.

For testing purposes I generate randomly any 128-bit X and any 128-bit prime P, and output solution for this X and P. You can see when you run my program, that for any large X and P solution is outputted immediately.

You can play around in my program with bit sizes, just go to main() function and replace 128 there with e.g. 256, to test 256 bit random numbers.

Besides mentioned algorithms I used two small extra algorithms - [Fermat Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test) and [Modular Exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) (using technique of exponentiation by squaring or binary exponentiation).

My program is broken into two big parts - first is regarding task without modulus, second part is with modulus. You can easily cut my program into two files, just find piece of text `=== Part 2 ===`, after it goes second idependant part.

Program compiles under [CLang](https://clang.llvm.org/) and [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). Right now under [MSVC](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) it doesn't compile only because it uses builtin 128-bit integer, `__int128`, which is only supported in CLang/GCC. But if you need MSVC I can easily fix this by using [Boost Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) library, just tell me. Also builtin `__int128` whill be faster than Boost's.

To compile second part of my program [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) is needed. It can be easily installed under Linux through `sudo apt install libboost-dev-all`. Under Windows a bit more difficult, but still can be installed through [Chocolatey's Boost Package](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/boost-msvc-14.3) (do `choco install boost-msvc-14.3`, but install [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) first).

But this Boost is needed only for second part of my program, with modulus. You can easily remove second part of my program and first part will be compiled without Boost, with standard library only.

See example output of my program after the code.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/P68no3e1n)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <stdexcept>

#define ASSERT_MSG(cond, msg) { if (!(cond)) { throw std::runtime_error("Assertion (" #cond ") failed at line " + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "! Msg '" + std::string(msg) + "'"); } }
#define ASSERT(cond) ASSERT_MSG(cond, "")
#define COUT(code) { std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(cout_mux); std::cout code; std::cout << std::flush; }

#if defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(__clang__)
    #define IS_MSVC 1
    #define IS_CLANG 0
    #define IS_GCC 0
#elif defined(__clang__)
    #define IS_MSVC 0
    #define IS_CLANG 1
    #define IS_GCC 0
#else
    #define IS_MSVC 0
    #define IS_CLANG 0
    #define IS_GCC 1
#endif

using i16 = int16_t;
using u16 = uint16_t;
using i32 = int32_t;
using u32 = uint32_t;
using i64 = int64_t;
using u64 = uint64_t;
using i128c = signed __int128;
using u128c = unsigned __int128;

std::mutex cout_mux;

template <typename T, typename F>
T BinarySearch(F const & f, T begin, T end) {
    auto const end0 = end;
    while (begin + 2 < end) {
        auto const mid = (begin + end - 1) / 2;
        if (f(mid))
            end = mid + 1;
        else
            begin = mid + 1;
    }
    for (auto i = begin; i < end; ++i)
        if (f(i))
            return i;
    return end0;
}

template <typename T, typename F>
T ExpSearch(F const & f, T begin, T end, bool back = false) {
    auto const begin0 = begin, end0 = end;
    T l = 0;
    if (!back) {
        for (l = 1;; l <<= 1) {
            if (begin0 + l >= end0)
                break;
            if (f(begin0 + l - 1))
                break;
            begin = begin0 + l;
        }
        end = std::min(begin0 + l, end0);
    } else {
        for (l = 1;; l <<= 1) {
            if (begin0 + l >= end0)
                break;
            if (!f(end0 - l))
                break;
            end = end0 - l + 1;
        }
        begin = std::max(begin0 + l, end0) - l;
    }
    if (begin >= end || !f(end - 1))
        return end0;
    return BinarySearch(f, begin, end);
}

#if defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(__clang__)
inline u64 UDiv128(u64 h, u64 l, u64 d, u64 * r) {
    return _udiv128(h, l, d, r);
}
#else
inline u64 UDiv128(u64 h, u64 l, u64 d, u64 * r) {
    u64 q;
    asm (R"(
        .intel_syntax
        mov rdx, %V[h]
        mov rax, %V[l]
        div %V[d]
        mov %V[r], rdx
        mov %V[q], rax
    )"
        : [q] "=r" (q), [r] "=r" (*r) : [h] "r" (h), [l] "r" (l), [d] "r" (d)
        : "rax", "rdx"
    );
    return q;
}
#endif

template <typename YT, YT Y, typename T>
YT Mod(T x) {
    static_assert(sizeof(T) <= 16);
    if (x <= u64(-1))
        return YT(u64(x) % Y);
    u64 constexpr mod = u64(-1) / Y * Y;
    u64 r, q = UDiv128(u64(x >> 64), u64(x), mod, &r);
    return YT(r % Y);
}

template <typename T>
bool FilterSquare(T const & x) {
    static u32 constexpr filt_primo = 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13;
    static auto const filt = []{
        std::vector<bool> filt(filt_primo);
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < filt_primo; ++i)
            filt[(uint64_t(i) * i) % filt_primo] = true;
        return std::move(filt);
    }();
    if constexpr(IS_CLANG)
        return filt[Mod<u32, filt_primo>(x)];
    else
        return filt[size_t(x % filt_primo)];
}

template <typename T>
std::string IntToStr(T n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return "0";
    bool sign = !(n >= 0);
    ASSERT(!sign);
    //if (sign) n = -n;
    u64 constexpr mod = 1'000'000'000'000'000'000ULL;
    std::string r;
    while (n >= mod) {
        u64 const rem = u64(n % mod);
        r = (std::ostringstream{} << std::setw(18) << std::setfill('0') << rem).str() + r;
        n /= mod;
    }
    r = (std::ostringstream{} << u64(n)).str() + r;
    if (sign)
        r = "-" + r;
    return r;
}

template <typename T>
void SolveNoMod(T x_begin, T x_end) {
    using MT = i128c;
    T constexpr Y_max = 1ULL << 62;
    T ylast = 0;
    for (T x = x_begin; x < x_end; ++x) {
        MT const right = MT(x) * x * x + x + 24;
        if (!FilterSquare(right)) continue;
        auto const f = [&](T y){ return MT(y) * y - right; };
        T const y = ExpSearch<T>([&](auto y){ return f(y) >= 0; }, ylast, Y_max);
        auto const fy = f(y);
        if (fy == 0)
            COUT(<< "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << std::endl);
        ylast = y;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void SolveNoModParallel(T x_begin, T x_end) {
    size_t const nthr = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::vector<std::future<void>> tasks;
    T constexpr block = 1 << 25;
    for (T x_cur = x_begin; x_cur < x_end; x_cur += block) {
        while (tasks.size() >= nthr) {
            for (ptrdiff_t i = ptrdiff_t(tasks.size()) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
                if (tasks[i].wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) == std::future_status::ready) {
                    tasks[i].get();
                    tasks.erase(tasks.begin() + i);
                }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
        T const x_begin0 = x_cur, x_end0 = std::min<T>(x_cur + block, x_end);
        if (x_begin0 >= x_end0)
            continue;
        tasks.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&, x_begin0, x_end0]{
            SolveNoMod<T>(x_begin0, x_end0);
        }));
    }
}

// ================ Part 2 ================

#include <random>
#include <bitset>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

#define bisizeof(x) (sizeof(x) * 8)
#define BiSize(T) (BiSizeS<T>::value)

using u128b = boost::multiprecision::uint128_t;
using u256 = boost::multiprecision::uint256_t;
using u512 = boost::multiprecision::uint512_t;

template <typename T> struct DWordOf;
template <> struct DWordOf<u32> { using type = u64; };
template <> struct DWordOf<u64> { using type = u128b; };
template <> struct DWordOf<u128b> { using type = u256; };
template <> struct DWordOf<u256> { using type = u512; };

template <typename T> struct BiSizeS : std::integral_constant<size_t, bisizeof(T)> {};
template <> struct BiSizeS<u32> : std::integral_constant<size_t, 32> {};
template <> struct BiSizeS<u64> : std::integral_constant<size_t, 64> {};
template <> struct BiSizeS<u128b> : std::integral_constant<size_t, 128> {};
template <> struct BiSizeS<u256> : std::integral_constant<size_t, 256> {};
template <> struct BiSizeS<u512> : std::integral_constant<size_t, 512> {};

template <typename T>
T All1() { return ~T(0); }

template <typename T>
std::string IntToStrBin(T x) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    for (size_t k = 0; k < BiSize(T); k += 16) {
        std::bitset<16> bs = u16(x >> k);
        auto bss = bs.to_string();
        std::reverse(bss.begin(), bss.end());
        ss << bss << " ";
    }
    return ss.str();
}

template <typename T>
T PowMod(T a, T b, T c) {
    using DT = typename DWordOf<T>::type;
    T r = 1;
    while (b) {
        if (b & 1)
            r = T((DT(r) * a) % c);
        a = T((DT(a) * a) % c);
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return r;
}

template <typename T>
int EulerCriterion(T n, T p) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    auto const val = PowMod(n, (p - 1) / 2, p);
    ASSERT(val == 1 || val == p - 1);
    return val == 1 ? 1 : -1;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> Uniquize(std::vector<T> vec) {
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());
    return std::move(vec);
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> SquareRoot_Mod4_3(T n, T p) {
    using DT = typename DWordOf<T>::type;
    ASSERT(p % 4 == 3);
    n %= p;
    T const r = PowMod(n, (p + 1) / 4, p);
    if ((DT(r) * r) % p == n % p)
        return Uniquize<T>(std::vector<T>({r, p - r}));
    return {};
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> SquareRoot_TonelliShanks(T n, T p) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm
    // see also https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1407.pdf
    using DT = typename DWordOf<T>::type;
    n %= p;
    ASSERT(p % 4 == 1);
    T Q = p - 1, S = 0;
    while ((Q & 1) == 0) {
        Q >>= 1;
        ++S;
    }
    T z = 0;
    for (z = 2; z < p; ++z)
        if (EulerCriterion(z, p) == -1)
            break;
    ASSERT_MSG(z < p, "n " + IntToStr(n) + ", p " + IntToStr(p));
    T M = S, c = PowMod(z, Q, p), t = PowMod(n, Q, p), R = PowMod(n, (Q + 1) / 2, p), r = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (t == 0) {
            r = 0;
            break;
        }
        if (t == 1) {
            r = R;
            break;
        }
        T sqt = t;
        size_t i = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < M; ++i) {
            sqt = T((DT(sqt) * sqt) % p);
            if (sqt == 1)
                break;
        }
        ASSERT(i < M);
        ASSERT(M - i - 1 < BiSize(T));
        T b = PowMod(c, T(1) << size_t(M - i - 1), p);
        M = i;
        c = T((DT(b) * b) % p);
        t = T((DT(t) * c) % p);
        R = T((DT(R) * b) % p);
    }
    ASSERT((DT(r) * r) % p == n);
    return Uniquize<T>(std::vector<T>({r, p - r}));
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> SquareRoot(T n, T p) {
    using DT = typename DWordOf<T>::type;
    n %= p;
    if (n == 0)
        return {0};
    if (p == 2)
        return {n};
    {
        auto const ec = EulerCriterion(n, p);
        ASSERT(ec == 1 || ec == -1);
        if (ec == -1)
            return {};
    }
    if (p % 4 == 3)
        return SquareRoot_Mod4_3(n, p);
    return SquareRoot_TonelliShanks(n, p);
}

auto & RNG() {
    thread_local std::mt19937_64 rng{(u64(std::random_device{}()) << 32) ^ u64(std::random_device{}())};
    //thread_local std::mt19937_64 rng{123};
    return rng;
}

template <typename T>
T Rand() {
    T r = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < BiSize(T); i += 64)
        r ^= T(RNG()()) << i;
    return r;
}

template <typename T>
size_t NumBits(T n) {
    size_t cnt = 0;
    while (n > 0xFF) {
        n >>= 8;
        cnt += 8;
    }
    while (n) {
        n >>= 1;
        ++cnt;
    }
    return cnt;
}

template <typename T>
T RandRange(T end) {
    if (end <= 1)
        return 0;
    size_t const bits = NumBits(end - 1);
    while (true) {
        auto n = Rand<T>() >> (BiSize(T) - bits);
        if (n < end)
            return n;
    }
}

template <typename T>
struct UniformIntDistr {
    UniformIntDistr(T a, T b) : a_(a), diff_(b + 1 - a) { ASSERT(a <= b); }
    template <typename R>
    T operator()(R & r) { return a_ + RandRange<T>(diff_); }
    T a_ = 0, diff_ = 0;
};

template <typename T>
T RandUni(T a, T b) {
    return UniformIntDistr<T>(a, b)(RNG());
}

template <typename T>
bool IsProbablyPrime_Fermat(T N) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test
    size_t const ntrials = 24;
    if (N <= 10)
        return N == 2 || N == 3 || N == 5 || N == 7;
    for (size_t trial = 0; trial < ntrials; ++trial)
        if (PowMod<T>(Rand<T>() % (N - 3) + 2, N - 1, N) != 1)
            return false;
    return true;
}

#define IsProbablyPrime IsProbablyPrime_Fermat

template <typename T>
T GenPrime(size_t bits) {
    ASSERT(bits >= 2);
    if (bits == 2)
        return RandUni(2, 3);
    ASSERT_MSG(1 <= bits && bits <= BiSize(T), "bits " + std::to_string(bits) + ", BiSize(T) " + std::to_string(BiSize(T)));
    auto const a = T(1) << (bits - 1), b = All1<T>() >> (BiSize(T) - bits);
    ASSERT_MSG(a <= b, "bits " + std::to_string(bits) + ", BiSize(T) " + std::to_string(BiSize(T)) + ", a\n" + IntToStrBin(a) + "\nb\n" + IntToStrBin(b));
    while (true) {
        auto const p = RandUni(a, b) | 1;
        if (IsProbablyPrime(p))
            return p;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void SolveMod(T x_begin, T mod) {
    using DT = typename DWordOf<T>::type;
    size_t cnt = 0;
    for (T x = x_begin;; ++x) {
        T const right = T((DT((DT(x) * x) % mod) * x + x + 24) % mod);
        for (auto const root: SquareRoot<T>(right, mod)) {
            ASSERT((DT(root) * root) % mod == right);
            COUT(<< "x = " << IntToStr(x) << ", y = " << IntToStr(root) << std::endl);
            ++cnt;
            if (cnt >= 1)
                return;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    try {
        COUT(<< "NoMod:" << std::endl);
        SolveNoModParallel<i64>(0, 1ULL << 25);
        
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
            auto const p = GenPrime<u128b>(128);
            COUT(<< "Mod p = " << IntToStr(p) << " (p % 4 = " << p % 4 << ")" << std::endl);
            SolveMod<u128b>(Rand<u128b>(), p);
        }
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
NoMod:
x = 12, y = 42
Mod p = 219688491259897122736212527051092113293 (p % 4 = 1)
x = 273903578792010575565282758244483002178, y = 58545642357590275355420738836818145161
Mod p = 331730100473713163326635571798951273061 (p % 4 = 1)
x = 250565107208593852657423435334728568634, y = 61465560240598325718665905365177214482
Mod p = 252783594113540225392633573791281784563 (p % 4 = 3)
x = 288516005161218077788215822752214504957, y = 117961729460812361108079791544444521231
Mod p = 215955488059493315966305338643349539739 (p % 4 = 3)
x = 89919490689630945164185961723990553146, y = 54128779781633285229073363977029067647
Mod p = 313197233417624767187155292666519557093 (p % 4 = 1)
x = 41108118867338545127706112908846297142, y = 20447436839455724175052447276214468753
Mod p = 263976413751637208893338879428427068801 (p % 4 = 1)
x = 165225955028296917988729655751990538414, y = 62234915643079594692200530956112078114
Mod p = 291337940475282224323312279077405757331 (p % 4 = 3)
x = 160948015593193411286972051949433960251, y = 65875958798817617640182672547677071647
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick a target, say y = 3; y^2 = 9.  Find an x value, x1, that gives a result of y1 <= 3.  Find a second x value, x2, that gives a result of y2 >= 3.  Given that your equation is continuous, then your target x value will be between x1 and x2.  Use binary search to find the closest x value within the limits of the real values allowed on your machine.

Alternatively, try different x1 and x2 until you find a pair with at least one integer between them.

Given the practical limitations of representing real numbers on a finite computer, you may only be able to find a solution that works to a limited number of decimal places: y = 3.0000000000120694... or whatever.